# Rails: Why association value can not be saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to save `schedule_id` in `amount` model.

Although I can save `room_id`, I can't save `schedule_id`.
There is no error.

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "amounts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "schedule_id"
    t.integer  "room_id"
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.integer  "ccy"
    t.decimal  "amount"
```

**models\schedule.rb**

```
  has_many :rooms, inverse_of: :schedule, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :amounts, inverse_of: :schedule, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :amounts, allow_destroy: true
```

**models\room.rb**

```
  belongs_to :schedule, inverse_of: :rooms
  has_many :amounts, inverse_of: :room, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :amounts, allow_destroy: true
```

**models\amount.rb**

```
  belongs_to :schedule, inverse_of: :amounts
  belongs_to :room, inverse_of: :amounts
  belongs_to :event, inverse_of: :amounts
```

**schedules_controller.rb**

```
  def new
    @schedule = Schedule.new
    room = @schedule.rooms.build
    room.amounts.build
  end

  def create
    @schedule = current_user.schedules.build(schedule_params)
    if @schedule.save
      flash[:success] = "schedule created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def schedule_params
      params.require(:schedule).permit(
        :title, :departure_date, 
        rooms_attributes: [
          :id, :_destroy, :room, :schedule_id, :day 
          amounts_attributes: [
            :id, :_destroy, :schedule_id, :room_id, :event_id, :ccy, :amount
          ]
        ]
      )
    end
```

**views\schedules\new.html.erb**

```
    <%= form_for(@schedule) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <%= render 'schedule_form', f: f %>
      <%= f.submit "Create my schedule", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <br>
    <% end %>
```

**views\schedules\ _schedule_form.html.erb**

`room_id` can be saved, but `schedule_id` can NOT be saved.

```
<%= f.fields_for(:rooms) do |r| %>
  <%= r.hidden_field :schedule_id %>
  <%= r.fields_for(:amounts) do |am| %>
    <%= am.hidden_field :schedule_id %>
    <%= am.hidden_field :room_id %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It would be appreciated if you could show me how to save `schedule_id`.

**UPDATE**

post the log.

```
Processing by SchedulesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "schedule"=>{"title"=>"test", "departure_date"=>"2016-08-28", "rooms_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"schedule_id"=>"", "amounts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"schedule_id"=>"", "room_id"=>""}}}}}, "commit"=>"Create my schedule"}
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "schedule"=>{"title"=>"test", "departure_date"=>"2016-08-28", "rooms_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"schedule_id"=>"", "amounts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"schedule_id"=>"", "room_id"=>""}}}}}, "commit"=>"Create my schedule"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (7.0ms)  INSERT INTO "schedules" ("title", "departure_date", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["title", "test"], ["departure_date", "2016-08-28"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-08-28 06:08:33.717879"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-28 06:08:33.717879"]]
  SQL (7.0ms)  INSERT INTO "schedules" ("title", "departure_date", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["title", "test"], ["departure_date", "2016-08-28"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-08-28 06:08:33.717879"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-28 06:08:33.717879"]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "rooms" ("schedule_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["schedule_id", 85], ["created_at", "2016-08-28 06:08:33.727435"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-28 06:08:33.727435"]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "rooms" ("schedule_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["schedule_id", 85], ["created_at", "2016-08-28 06:08:33.727435"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-28 06:08:33.727435"]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "amounts" ("room_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["room_id", 105], ["created_at", "2016-08-28 06:08:33.730019"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-28 06:08:33.730019"]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "amounts" ("room_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["room_id", 105], ["created_at", "2016-08-28 06:08:33.730019"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-28 06:08:33.730019"]]
   (5.6ms)  COMMIT
   (5.6ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to https://xxx/schedules/85
Redirected to https://xxx/schedules/85
Completed 302 Found in 197ms (ActiveRecord: 14.2ms)
Completed 302 Found in 197ms (ActiveRecord: 14.2ms)
```

Comment: `f.fields_for(:rooms) do |r|` object is **r**, but you're using **a**.  `a.hidden_field :schedule_id`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Emu. I made typo. Although I use `r` instead of `a`, result is the same. It would be appreciated if you could give me advice.

Comment: When you submit the form what parameters are passed in `schedule_params`? If you can check that you can get a good insight.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Emu. When I check the log, `schedule_id`  is not inserted. `SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "amounts" ("room_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["room_id", 105], ["created_at", "2016-08-28 06:08:33.730019"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-28 06:08:33.730019"]]` Do you have any guess?

Comment: @SamuraiBlue post the logs. the request logs where we can see the params hash.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Paulo Abreu. I post the logs. It would be appreciated if you could give me advice.

Comment: try removing <%= r.hidden_field :schedule_id %> in the create process.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Paulo Abreu. Although I remove `<%= r.hidden_field :schedule_id %>`, the result is the same.

Comment: you removed it from both places? `am.hidden_field :schedule_id`

Comment: so, what happens is that you nest ammounts in Room, and what is set is ammounts.rooms_id in Ammount. and you nest rooms in Schedule, so it sets rooms.schedule_id. That is how accepts_nested_attributes_for works by default. You will need to set ammounts.schedule_id  manually os override amounts_attributes= at Ammount model to get the paren schedule id and assign it on the account instances.  I have to say that I find your models relations really confusing and its seems that everything is pointing to everything.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue Could you show what you are getting as `schedule_params` in the create action

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @ techdreams. What should I show you? I already posted `schedules_controller.rb` and `log` in my question. Sorry for not getting what you want.

Comment: You say "There is no error.", but you never call `.errors` on any of your records, so how would you know for sure? Call this after attempting to save the record.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @max pleaner. I add `shared/error_messages` in the `schedules\new.html.erb`. Although I wrote `<% if object.errors.any? %>` and display message if any error in `shared/error_messages`, but no error is appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to save the `schedule_id` in the `Amount` model you need to set manually the `scheudle_id` value with a callback.

```
class Amount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room
  belongs_to :schedule

  before_save do
    self.schedule_id = room.schedule_id
  end
end
```

This is because you are using a `Schedule` form with its `rooms` and the `amounts` that belongs to this specific room, but the `Amount` can't be notified of the schedule because the direct association with `Schedule` is not used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Alejandro Babio. It works!

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove reference keys from the private method,

      private
      def schedule_params
        params.require(:schedule).permit(
          :title, :departure_date, 
          rooms_attributes: [
           :day, 
            amounts_attributes: [
              :ccy, :amount
            ]
          ]
        )
      end

    Remove all hidden fields from view files.
```